# Overloads not typechecking body

Tags: typescript, types, overloading

Does TypeScript not check the function body against function overloads at all?
The following compiles, although it clearly isn't doing what it claims:

```
function a(input: string): string
function a(input: number): number
function a(input: string | number): string | number {
  if (typeof input === "string") return 42
  return "banana"
}
```

Is my third signature at fault? The catch-all signature isn't appearing in the resulting type, and I don't know of a way to declare the function without it, any attempt is met with the `Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation.`
 error.

```
typeof a = {
    (input: string): string;
    (input: number): number;
}
```

I would accept switching to the more explicit intersect type:

```
type C = ((input: number) => number) & ((input: string) => string)
```

But I don't understand how to actually create a function satisfying it without using overload syntax, which seems like a forced cast. I asked about that in [Overloaded function type in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132459/overloaded-function-type-in-typescript) question.

**Edit:** the first block is a minimalist contrived example. You can test it with the following:

```
const number: number = a(0)
console.log("number", typeof number, number)
```

outputs `number string banana`

```
const string: string = a("")
console.log("string", typeof string, string)
```

outputs `string number 42`

**Edit 2:** This isn't a duplicate of [Overloaded function type in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132459/overloaded-function-type-in-typescript), I am asking about typechecking the function implementation against all overloads, that question is about fulfilling an overload type with a new function.

Comment: What I don't understand is why you have a declaration `function a(input: string): string` when that never happens. Same thing with `function a(input: number): number`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts that's a contrived example of the error this is supposed to catch.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood then. The reason it compiles is because your last declaration `function a(input: string | number): string | number`. If _any_ declaration matches the relationship between the input and the return value, then the call will compile.

Comment: (1) I can't remove that declaration. (2) That signature isn't actually present in `typeof a`, only the distinct two are. (3) As seen in the edit, it's lying to the code using it!

Comment: (1) Yes you can, just begin the body after the second overload. (2) Your `typeof a = ...` does not compile, so that's irrelevant. You can't assign to the expression `typeof a`. (3) You haven't actually produced a [mcve]. Try again.

Comment: That's a printout of the type for a. That is not something  you should write or compile.

Comment: here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20a(input%3A%20string)%3A%20string%0D%0Afunction%20a(input%3A%20number)%3A%20number%0D%0Afunction%20a(input%3A%20string%20%7C%20number)%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(typeof%20input%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22)%20return%2042%0D%0A%20%20return%20%22banana%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20number%3A%20number%20%3D%20a(0)%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22number%22%2C%20typeof%20number%2C%20number)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20string%3A%20string%20%3D%20a(%22%22)%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22string%22%2C%20typeof%20string%2C%20string)

Comment: [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20a(input%3A%20string)%3A%20string%0D%0Afunction%20a(input%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(typeof%20input%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22)%20return%2042%0D%0A%20%20return%20%22banana%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20number%3A%20number%20%3D%20a(0)%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22number%22%2C%20typeof%20number%2C%20number)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20string%3A%20string%20%3D%20a(%22%22)%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22string%22%2C%20typeof%20string%2C%20string))

Comment: No, not "here". Please try to fix the implementation and see what happens.

Comment: `that's a contrived example of the error this is supposed to catch.` According to you, the implementation is _not supposed to compile_. By using only the correct forward declarations as you requested, it _fails to compile by design_. I don't see the problem here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179257/discussion-between-mihail-malostanidis-and-patrick-roberts).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloaded function type in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132459/overloaded-function-type-in-typescript)

Answer (score 3):

> Does TypeScript not check the function body against function overloads at all?

No it does not check the body against overload declarations.

As you've seen, it checks that implementation signature is compatible with all overload declarations; and it checks that the body conforms to the implementation signature; that's all. Also, the implementation signature is not taken into account when doing overload resolution at the call site.

Enforcing implementation conformance with overloaded declarations was not the design goal, at least that's how I interpret this statement from the [FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-am-i-getting-supplied-parameters-do-not-match-any-signature-error):

> The rationale here is that since JavaScript does not have function
>   overloading, you will be doing parameter checking in your function,
>   and this your function implementation might be more permissive that
>   what you would want your users to call you through.

Comment: Less permissive I can understand, my problem is that it allows outright lies to be asserted, something  you would only normally expect from a full on `(x as any) as Y` casting. It's not really well documented anywhere just how perilous this is. One can easily see refactoring the body and introducing an error like in the question.