# Typescript enforcing function return types based on template variable

Tags: typescript, function, templates, casting, return

In Typescript you can overload functions in order to have different return types based on the input parameters:

```js
function test2(b: true): {a: number};
function test2(b: false): {x: number};
function test2(b: boolean): {a: number} | {x: number} {
  if(b) return {a: 1};

  return {x: 1};
}

const a_t2: {a: number} = test2(true);
const x_t2: {x: number} = test2(false);
```

I am looking for a way to implicitly enforce the return type inside the function itself. Typescript will not throw an error if you write this function body instead:

```js
function test2(b: true): {a: number};
function test2(b: false): {x: number};
function test2(b: boolean): {a: number} | {x: number} {
  // breaking the contract 
  if(b === false) return {a: 1};

  return {x: 1};
}
```

The closest I got to a working solution is this example, although it throws some errors:

```js
function test<B extends boolean>(b: B): B extends true ? {a: number} : {x: number} {
  if(b) {
    // Type '{ a: number; }' is not assignable to type 'B extends true ? { a: number; } : { x: number; }'.(2322)
    return {a: 1};
  } else {
    // Type '{ x: number; }' is not assignable to type 'B extends true ? { a: number; } : { x: number; }'.(2322)
    return {x: 2};
  }
}

const a_t = test(true);  // {a: number}
const x_t = test(false); // {b: number}
```

I could get around this error by casting the return values as:

```js
  if(b) {
    return {a: 1} as B extends true ? {a: number} : never;
  } else {
    return {x: 2} as B extends true ? never : {x: number};
  }
```

but it defeats the purpose of being implicitly strict with the return value.

Does anyone know of a better solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overloads not typechecking body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132520/overloads-not-typechecking-body)

Comment: Thanks, Roberto. It's a good answer but it only talks about function overloading. I am aware that overloading does not check return types. I'm trying to arrive at a solution using templates to type-check the return value. Though I'm not sure if that's even possible

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67712372/3388225. There are some solutions. But generally you are better off just checking it manually

Comment: Thanks @aleksxor for the link. I've found that what I'm asking for is [here, in this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912). By the looks of it, I'm out of luck with this one. I was looking for type safety in case someone (or even me) a couple of years down the line changes the function body and doesn't pay attention to the implementation or misses a possible branch in the return type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, there is a similar question and an answer here [stackoverflow.com/a/67712372/3388225](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67712372/3388225)

It nicely explains why it's not possible yet to do what I'm asking in my original question and there's a Typescript Github Issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) about this exact thing.