# Typing `this` parameters in overloaded function involving declaration merging?

Tags: typescript

I'm getting a type error for the following code:

[image]

I'm not quite sure why, the error says `Type 'Cash' is not assignable to type 'string'`. If I don't type the `this` parameter it works:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I'm using TS v3.1.3.

Here's the code:

```
class Cash {}

interface Cash {
  text (): string;
  text ( text: string ): this;
}

Cash.prototype.text = function ( text?: string ) {
  return text === undefined ? 'foo' : this;
};
```

Comment: In your example, `Cash` is a type, not an object. So it doesn't have a prototype, and you should be getting an error based on that, not because `Cash` isn't a string. Why are you trying to set the prototype of `Cash`?

Comment: You're trying to create a method on the interface itself, instead of an object that implements that interface

Comment: That's only portion of the code, there's actually a `Cash` class, in fact you can see that the second screenshot I attached it doesn't display any errors.

Comment: That seems a bit exaggerated, having a `class Cash {}` is all that's missing. In fact let me update my question with a reproducible code.

Comment: Question update, I hope you have all the info that you need now.

Comment: Is it possible you're confused about what exactly `this` is? `this` isn't actually a parameter in the usual sense of the word, and if you're coming from a language like Python, that can be a bit odd. [Suggested reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: My code isn't JavaScript, it's TypeScript, `this` is a fake parameter in this case. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Comment: Also as you can see the type checking doesn't display any error for my second screenshot. And it also works if I don't overload the `text` function. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message should say, the return type of your anonymous function, `Cash | "foo"`, is not assignable to the return type of either of the call signatures of `Cash.prototype.text`.  As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52214386), you'll need to either (1) use a type assertion or (2) define a named overloaded function (with two call signatures and an implementation signature) and then assign that function to `Cash.prototype.text`.

Assuming you have `noImplicitThis` disabled, if you don't annotate the `this` parameter, then it defaults to `any`.  For better or for worse, the union of `any` with anything is `any`, so the return type of the anonymous function comes out as `any` and is compatible with the return types of both call signatures of `Cash.prototype.text`.  That would be why you don't get an error in that case.  I highly recommend using `noImplicitThis` (in fact, all of `strict`) to avoid such surprises.

I can't reproduce the lack of an error when `Cash.prototype.text` is not overloaded: when I keep one of the call signatures and comment out the other, I still get the error.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I didn't express myself correctly, what I meant to say is that if the signature is `text ( text?: string ): string | this;` it works, but if I overload this signature with `text (): string` for instance it stops working.