# Typescript: Expand existing function definition

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create a new function definition based on an existing one?

For example, I have a third-party library that has the following two functions:

```js
declare function v1(s: string, t: string): string;
declare function v2(n: number): string;
```

I have a function that was written in JS but recently has been requested to add Typescript definitions. My function looks like the following:

```js
function useId(version, ...args) {
    return generators[version](...args);
}
```

What I would like to do is take the existing v1 and v2 declarations and use them in my own like so:

```js
declare function useId(v: "v1", ...v1): string;
declare function useId(v: "v2", ...v2): string;
```

I have not been able to find any advanced typings that cover this specific need but wanted to check before taking a longer more verbose route to adding my function definitions (given they'll be duplicates with one new parameter out front).

Comment: That seems very promising, I will look into it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the question "[Is there ArgumentsType<T> like ReturnType<T> in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51299555/1426891)", you can use [`Parameters<T>` and `ReturnType<T>`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1496) to refer to the parameters and return type of a known function `T`. If you type the `...args` parameters with that type, it will include those parameters in your signature.

```js
declare function useId(v: "v1", ...args: Parameters<typeof v1>):
    ReturnType<typeof v1>;
declare function useId(v: "v2", ...args: Parameters<typeof v2>):
    ReturnType<typeof v2>;

useId("v1", "s", "t");
useId("v2", 9001);
```

If you are doing this repeatedly, you can use a callable interface type to represent the overload. (It may otherwise be difficult to specify the overload as a union, as in the question [Overloaded function type in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52132459/1426891).) If you need to do this a lot, I imagine you could even use mapped types or other cleverness to represent the relationship between your wrapper and your original function(s).

```js
interface WrapperInterface<
    V1 extends (...args: any) => any,
    V2 extends (...args: any) => any> {
  (version: "v1", ...args: Parameters<V1>): ReturnType<V1>;
  (version: "v2", ...args: Parameters<V2>): ReturnType<V2>;
}

declare const useId2: WrapperInterface<typeof v1, typeof v2>;

useId2("v1", "s", "t");
useId2("v2", 9001);
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwDcBGACgGcAueMjGLVAcwBp4Mqa7GBKd2+hgNwBYAFChIsBCnTY8hAEwlUVVMgC2AIxAwe1Po2EjR46HCRpMufMjIgAksBIEqAImIuWAOm+wGleAAKsFBqIBjaZAA8GACeAA4gOIiERAB8ugBKYcgwqAAq8SDRhUkpqYYmkuYyVvA29o7O8G7yHvDenr7+QTAhYRHFCaUE8ulUWRg5+YWDickj5aKi9Q4kbkRtLmSbGC5chiuOLW0AnAAMZ0T7SyL04TCIUGAIAOq9cQkwdqj3j8+RADUiPAQAAPcKoYBkeAkDpdKhQVAxLjwAC8qXgiJiLAB8hB4JAkOhsJ8MD8CKRKPRmKRGIA3qJ4DCCBErK53F5SeTAsFQvcokCxvAJlMCglAWlDEynKy8OzWpzOmTurz+jABaNMtlcmKirjFiIAL43SpmMB4Gh1WwOeRUN5QD7ab6-J5FWJDeZEFjuuYKA3La3ARTrTbbFguXbXESHYMjU4XK6GIA)